# Connection with a PostgreSQL foreign table

Tags: r, postgresql, citus

I'm using citus columnar extension cstore_fdw for PostgreSQL (I'm on 9.4.1).

I create the foreign table without any problem.

The problem starts in R when I try to write into it.

A normal `dbWriteTable` command does not work:

```
cba <- dbWriteTable(conpg, name=dataDt1_, value=df, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"PostgreSQLConnection", "db.table", "data.frame"’
```

Considering that for PostgreSQL a foreign table can be a csv, a table on another server, a columnar store etc., does anybody have experience accessing any of the above with R?

Comment: I've just found out that cstore does not yet support `INSERT` `ALTER` and `DELETE`: this could explain why I cannot write into the table.  On the other hand my question stands to see if anybody has experience in accessing any  (other) type of foreign table with R.

Answer (score 2):

cstore_fdw doesn't support `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. version 1.2 added support for `INSERT INTO cstore_table SELECT ...`, but the support for single row inserts is still missing.

Currently you can append data to a cstore table in one of the following ways:

- Use the `COPY` command
- Use `INSERT INTO cstore_table SELECT ...`

Comment: thanks this clarifies the situation with cstore_fdw (great product bdw).  I am still a bit at a loss on how to use it with R. I will try ```dbSendQuery``` from the ```DBI``` package and report.